# How to implement Facebook recommendation on Native Ad placement

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I am using facebook native ad in a dialog and using Facebook native ad template to render the ad. Still, Facebook is showing me to update the placement and marking some region that these areas shouldn't contain any clickable content.

> Facebook Recommendation

[image: Facebook Recommendation]

> How I am rendering ad

```
@Override
public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
   mFanAdView = NativeAdView.render(activity, fanNativeAd, NativeAdView.Type.HEIGHT_300);
}
```

> My implementation looks like this

[image: My implementation looks like this]

Now, my question is what should I do when I am using **Facebook templates?**

Comment: Having the same issue, Facebook templates not passing their own quality check, ironic, isn't it?